# HL7 HAPI-FHIR add cookie to the client request

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi

Is it possible to add cookie to the request while using IRestFulClient from HAPI-FHIR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done quite easily by creating a custom interceptor which adds a cookie header. You can see an example of a client interceptor which adds an authorization header [here](https://github.com/jamesagnew/hapi-fhir/blob/master/hapi-fhir-base/src/main/java/ca/uhn/fhir/rest/client/interceptor/BearerTokenAuthInterceptor.java). If you copy that code but change the header from "Authorization" to "Cookie", then register the interceptor by calling

```
client.registerInterceptor(interceptor);
```

..you will get that behaviour.

Incidentally, if you create such an interceptor and wanted to share it back with the project, we'd love to have it! :)

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your quick response:) I created a new interceptor and it works for my cases. https://github.com/jamesagnew/hapi-fhir/pull/35